# Microsoft access auto generate student id based on first and last name + a number

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access database with a student table. The first three fields in the table are studentID, ForeName and LastName.

The table already contains about 35 student records. The student ID is of the form AA0000. The first two characters are made up of the first letter of Last Name and First Name. The 0000 is a 4 digit number.

I have created a form for data entry into the student table. I want the student ID to be autogenerated according to the following rules

- The first two characters are the first letter of the last and first name respectively
- The 4 digit number is 1 greater than the largest 4 digit number already used

so for example if I have only the student ID's AA1256, BC1267 and OK1288 in the table, the number of the next record I add should be 1289.

Is it possible to achieve this by only changing the control source of the sutdentID text box on the form I've created.

I've tried putting the following code in the control source of studentID (doesn't work though)
=Left(LastName,1) & left(forename,1) & (max(right(studentID,4))+1)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I think this attempt is close, but only refers to the studentID in the current record - you need a way to get to the max studentID in the full table.  One simple way may be to prepare a query to get that value by itself, then use that new query in your form.

Comment: Actually that's what I've just tried but even that gives me an error.

Comment: what breaks?  Does the new query return the correct result?  If it does, can you post the new code that uses it?  If not, then you need to troubleshoot that query 1st.

Comment: Actually that's what I've just tried but even that gives me an error.
I have a query that gives me maxNum+1
What I've tried putting in the control source is now something like
Left(LastName,1) & left(forename,1) & CurMaxNum!Expr1
but this gives me a #Name error :(

Comment: The code in the query is 
SELECT Max(Right([StudentID],4))+1 AS Expr1
FROM Student;

Comment: by the way, the first part of the expression that gets the first letter of the names works fine. It's trying to get the number that breaks it

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is because your formula doesn't have square brackets around the field names.

Try:

> `Left([LastName],1) & left([forename],1) & (max(right([studentID],4))+1)`

Answer (score 0):

The control source needs to remain studentid and should be disabled or locked. I would set the form's "Before Insert" property to "[Event Procedure]" and enter the following VBA code in the auto-created Form_BeforeInsert sub:

```
studentid=left(LastName,1) & left(ForeName,1) & _
    Right("0000" & CStr(CInt(Nz(DMax("right(studentid,4)","Student"),0))+1),4)
```

I see a issue where, if the student name changes (as in being corrected immediately after adding), the ID would need to change.  If it is the primary key, you'd need to delete and re-add the record with the new key.  If not, you could update studentid in the "Before Insert" event handler using similar code. I'd watch for nulls in the student names too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. This kind of works. I think I'll put the code under a command button "Generate Student ID".
I will need to look up on things like DMax and Nz, these aren't things I've used before.
Is there a way to refer to a query within VBA. Because I have a query called CurMaxNum that has the next number I want to use!

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: The DMax function will give the maximum value without having to create a separate query.  The Nz function (Null to zero) just keeps the line of code from failing if there are no records in Student. The rest of it takes care of converting the last number from a string to integer, incrementing it, then turning it back into a zero padded numeric string.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that "adding" a string and numeric 1 doesn't work.

So try using Max on the numeric value, add 1, and format to four digits:

```
=Left(LastName,1) & Left(ForeName,1) & Format(Max(Val(Right(studentID,4)))+1,"0000")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment but this didn't quite work.
LIke Kevin mentioned below, the control source needs to remain StudentID so that the value is stored in the table. His suggestion worked.
thanks very much for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think the real answer here is to not bother, just calculate the ID and display it wherever you need it. After all you know all the values involved.

Reference everything else back to the unique PK which is the numeric StudentID. That way if someone changes their name, gets married etc the Unique ID hasn't altered just what you display.